# Read equation from text

Tags: c++, string, stack, queue

Hello I am making a program that uses linked lists, stack, and queues to convert infix to postfix and solve the equation. I have made a Push, Pull, etc, for the stack and queue linked list. However the problem that I am having is converting between char and float.

When I read in from the text file, I convert the equation into a string, simple equation like 2+3/(5+1). My push function takes in a char and the pull returns a char. What I can't figure out what to do first is how to convert these strings to char/floats. I wrote this test code to see if typeid would distinguish the char and int.

```
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<lines; i++){
    j = 0;
    while(readIn[i][j] != '\0'){
        cout << typeid(readIn[i][j]).name();
        j++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

However my result looks like this:

```
ccccccccccccccc
ccccccccccccccccccccc
ccccccccc
```

So it's interpreting every character in the string as a char.

And my second question involves the pull function. In the push function, once I can get the char to float conversion correctly, I did a function overload, one with char and the other with a float. Exact same code, just stores the data into a separate part of the structure. However in the pull function, how can I pull either the char or float? I need one pull function to return a char and the other a float, but you can't have 2 functions with the same argument and different returns, I am a little lost.

I really appreciate any help!!

Comment: C != C++, and it looks like you are using `std::cout`, so this is a C++ question?

Comment: And, what do you think `typeid` will do in this case?

Comment: I guess that `readIn` is an array of arrays of `char`? In that case it's not surprising that each character is a character... To know what kind ot character you have read, you have to actually examine the actual character.

Comment: You might want to go to your favorite search engine and look for things like "lexer" and "parser" and "expression parser".

Comment: This is a C++. And I was expecting typeid to output, icicci (or some sort of that combination of char, aka operands, and integers).

Comment: You shouldn't expect that, the type has nothing to do with the value, `3` is the integer `3` and `'3'` is the character `3`, so both exists, and `typeid` will not check for the value, but for the type of the array elements.

Comment: Ah, what would you suggest using? I was looking into atoi(), however when it reaches an operand, how will it behave?

Comment: @Maty Using atoi is discouraged as it has undefined behaviour when it is not an int. It is best to use strtol instead. In any case though all of this information is available on http://www.cplusplus.com/.

Comment: Alright thanks. I love the downvoting on this website. I have put so much time into this code, I come to stackoverflow as a last resort, but none of that matters. If you're not an expert programmer, every question looks stupid to you. Thanks for absolutely no help from any one of you, especially that first comment (it was critical that you pointed that out).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, whether i understand your question correctly. You simply want to know, what a char in your string represents (digit, letter, points, ...)?

In this case, I would use the C-functions

```
 isalpha(c); // != 0, if c is a letter
 isdigit(c); // != 0, if c is a digit
 isspace(c); // != 0, if c is space, tab, ...
```